# Installing SimpleSamlPHP 1.18.3 on Apache 2.4.29 outside web root

Tags: php, apache, single-sign-on, homestead, simplesamlphp

This is my first time setting up SSO and I am wondering if anyone has experience with the following setup...Installing a SimpleSamlPHP SP App outside the webroot. For the testing stage, I am running a local Homestead/Vagrant setup with Apache set instead of Nginx. Example site mapped `site1.test`

My steps so far following this guide are as follows - https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-install

**1) Download** latest SimpleSamlPHP stable version (1.18.3) and place it outside the webroot. Structure below.

> SimpleSAMLPhp = /home/vagrant/code/site1/simplesamlphp/
>
> Web Root = /home/vagrant/code/site1/web/

**2) Apache config** - code placed in "/etc/apache2/mods-enabled" not "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled" as it does not seem to work with the Alias and read somewhere with the latest Apache (2.4.29) it must go in alias config instead.

```
SetEnv SIMPLESAMLPHP_CONFIG_DIR /home/vagrant/code/site1/simplesamlphp/config

Alias /simplesamlphp/www /home/vagrant/code/site1/simplesamlphp/www

<Directory /home/vagrant/code/site1/simplesamlphp/www>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**3) Config/config.php** added with a `baseurlpath` same as `Alias`

When visiting the URL `https://site1.test/simplesamlphp/www` `https://site1.test/simplesamlphp/www/admin` or I am not receiving any 404 or 403 pages..So I feel the `Alias` is at least working to some degree but the interface panel does not render, instead, I get the following:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Unable to load Composer autoloader in
>   /home/vagrant/code/site1/simplesamlphp/lib/_autoload.php on line 19
>
> **Functions**
>
> {main}( )
>   require_once(
>   '/home/vagrant/code/site1/simplesamlphp/www/_include.php' )
>   require_once(
>   '/home/vagrant/code/site1/simplesamlphp/lib/_autoload.php'
>   )
>
> **Locations**
>
> .../index.php:0 
>   .../index.php:3 
>   .../_index.php:4

If trying to access the URL `https://site1.test/simplesamlphp/www/module.php/core/frontpage_welcome.php` page says

> No input selected

I have also run `$ npm install` & `$ npm build` just incase but I believe not needed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Tony

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by updating/fresh install to version 1.18.4